# How to run RootSearch with increased WorkingPrecision?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I have a Sturm-Liouville problem on a finite interval $0\leq z \leq 1$. I integrate the one-dimensional ordinary differential equation of the second order (the LoDestro equation) by the shooting method. First, I get the solution of the LoDestro equation with boundary conditions $\psi(0)=1$, $\psi'(0)=0$ on the left boundary $z=0$, using the built-in function `ParametricNDValue` with free parameters $\beta$ and $\Lambda$.

It returns the value of the derivative $\psi[\beta,\Lambda]'(1)$ on the right boundary as a function of the specified parameters. Next, I try to find $\Lambda $ as the root of the equation $\psi[\beta,\Lambda]'(1)=0$ for a given value of $\beta$ using the built-in function `FindRoot` and the private function `RootSearch` by Ted Ersek.

At $\beta=0.99999$ the `RootSearch` function actually hangs, and the `FindRoot` function finds the root if the `WorkingPrecision->30` option is added:

```
FindRoot[eqn2[\[Beta]m, \[Lambda]] == 0
 , {\[Lambda], \[Lambda]start, \[Lambda]min, \[Lambda]max}
 , AccuracyGoal -> 4, PrecisionGoal -> 8
 , WorkingPrecision -> 30
 , EvaluationMonitor :> 
  Print[{"FindRoot: ", \[Beta]m, NumberForm[\[Lambda], {20, 18}], 
    eqn2[\[Beta]m, \[Lambda]], monitor++}]
 ]
```

But the `RootSearch` function does not have this option.

```
RootSearch[
 eqn2[\[Beta]m, \[Lambda]] == 
  0, {\[Lambda], \[Lambda]min, \[Lambda]max}
 , InitialSamples -> 10
 , RootTest -> (Abs[#2] < 0.001 &) 
 ]
```

I tried passing this option to the `ParametricNDValue` function,

```
pf2 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{ode2$[z, k, \[Beta], Rm, {q, Km}, 
     1 + \[Lambda]^4] == 0, \[Phi][0] == 1, \[Phi]'[0] == 
    0}, {\[Phi]'[zR$], \[Phi][zR$]}, {z, 0, (1 + 10^-7) zR$}
  , {{\[Beta], 0, 1}, {\[Lambda], 0, 10}}
  , Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}
  (*,WorkingPrecision\[Rule]30*)
  ]
```

but got a diagnostic

> ParametricNDSolveValue::initf : The initialization of the method
> NDSolve`StateSpace failed.

**Is it possible to teach `RootSearch` to work with increased accuracy?**

Comment: Would something on the lines of `Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision=200,$MinPrecision = 50,$MaxPrecision=Infinity }, (*your code*)]` help?

Comment: Isn't this a question for the author of `RootSearch`?

Comment: @rhermans: Thank you for your advice. But for now, I found another solution. First, I made the replacement $\Lambda=1+\lambda^4$, then I interpolate the equation, then `RootSearch` and `FindRoot` instantly find its solution.