# Bug in RootSearch

Tags: equation-solving

I ran into a problem with Ted Ersek's `RootSearch` (https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/4482/) while solving the problem described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/270219/how-to-run-rootsearch-with-increased-workingprecision). `RootSearch` sometimes hangs after reporting that a number is less than the smallest number allowed in the Wolfram Mathematica. The reason turned out to be the internal function `Ulp2`. It entered into an infinite loop if its first argument `x1` was  equal to `0.` (That's right: zero with a dot). Here is the corrected version of this function:

```
Ulp2=Function[{x1,x2},
      Module[{eps,sgn=Sign2[x2-x1],tol},
        (*Print["RootSearch Ulp2: sgn=",sgn,", x1=",x1,", x2=",x2];*)
        Which[
          (*test1*)sgn==0,
          (*Print["RootSearch Ulp2-0: sgn=",sgn,", x1=",x1,", x2=",x2];*)
          Message[Ulp2::fail];Throw[False],
          (*test2*)MachineNumberQ[x1],
          (*Print["***RootSearch Ulp2-test2: MachineNumberQ[x1]=",MachineNumberQ[x1]];*)
          (*tol=$MachineEpsilon*Max[Abs[x1],$MinMachineNumber]/2;*)
          tol=Max[$MachineEpsilon*Abs[x1],$MinMachineNumber];
          (*Print["***RootSearch Ulp2-test2: tol=",NumberForm[tol,{40,36}]];*)
          While[(eps=Plus@@{x1+sgn*tol,-x1})==0.0,tol*=2];
          (*Print["***RootSearch Ulp2-test2: eps=",eps];*)
          Abs[eps],
          (*test3*)True,
          (*Print["***RootSearch Ulp2-test3: sgn=",sgn];*)
          Block[{$MinPrecision=0},
            tol=SetPrecision[16*10^-Accuracy[x1],20];
            
            While[(eps=Plus@@{x1+sgn*tol,-x1};Precision[eps]<=0),
              tol*=2];
            SetPrecision[Abs[eps],20]
            ]
          ]
        ]];
```

Diagnostics came from the line

```
tol=$MachineEpsilon*Max[Abs[x1],$MinMachineNumber]/2;
```

The `tol` paramter was evaluated to `0` in this line so the next line enters to endless cycle:

```
While[(eps=Plus@@{x1+sgn*tol,-x1})==0.0,tol*=2];
```

I have changed definition of `tol` as follows:

```
tol=Max[$MachineEpsilon*Abs[x1],$MinMachineNumber];
```

which seems to me more adequate. **Can someone propose a more robust solution?**

Comment: If `RootSearch` is not part of Mathematica itself, then please include a link, otherwise everyone interested will have to use a search engine. Also, I understand the tag "bugs" to be for bugs in Mathematica itself, but I am just a random user.

Comment: I think questions of the form "Is this correct" will rarely have a definite answer in floating point matters. The original code allows for `$MachineEpsilon*$MinMachineNumber` which produces a warning message, so I agree that that does not make much sense. But numerical code always has edge cases, even more so if it is by a third party. So if your solution works, and you can validate it, why not run with it.

Comment: I don't think this is a good fit for this site. It appears to be not a question, but a bug report. It should go directly to the package's author. Have you contacted him before posting here?

Comment: It looks to me that instead of insisting on using RootSearch, which has not been touched in a long while, you should be using any of the other alternatives presented in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5663).

Comment: @J.M.: Solutions based on Plot and its associated documented and undocumented functions are slow for more or less complex equations. I have my own version of RootSearch with all known bugs fixed.

Comment: @Szabolcs: I tried to contact the package's author in the past, but he did not react.